# How to change "and" to ampersand, & in citations using BibDesk?

Tags: citing, natbib, texshop, bibdesk, ampersand

So I have TeXShop for mac, and this comes with BibDesk. Have used BibDesk to create a database with all my references in, and am using this with TeXShop in my LaTeX document. My advisor wants me to use an ampersand instead of "and" in my citations, and also possibly my bibliography. Have found many answers saying to edit the .bst file etc, all for use with biblatex, which I am not using.

At the moment I am using natbib, which I like. But the main problem is that I do not have a .bst file to edit, nor even a .bbl file as I am using this BibDesk- I do not even know how to edit the file BibDesk produces. Also not great at programming so getting very confused! Please please help I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: This is a problem with the .bst file, wot with BibDesk. May I suggest it is much easier to do using `biblatex`.

Comment: @Bernard how do I go about that? I can't even find the .bst file?

Comment: You can find the .bst file: it  should be one of the three files in `TeXMFRoot/bibtex/bst/natbib`. I just say it it harder to patch a .bst file than to customise with `biblatex` which does not use .bst files, but its own macros which written as normal latex macros.

Comment: @referencingstressesmeout - the bst ("bibliography style") file is given as the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction.

Comment: @Bernard, how do I use biblatex?

Comment: @Mico I know the style I am using at the moment is apalike, I just don't understand where this file will be located- all that texshop generates for me is a .bbl file, a .bcf file, and a .blg file?

Comment: have you tried {\&} in the entries and recompile your `.bib`? that's what I'd do

Comment: @Naphaneal thank you for the suggestion, I tried it but it didn't work- have read somewhere its because bibtex/bibdesk whatever just generates data, it cannot be edited like that as it only recognises 'and' as a splitter between authors, not \&.

Comment: TeXshop is just a front end; it does *not* generate the bbl and blg files. Those are generated by BibTeX (which is invoked by TeXshop), based on information provided in the aux and bst files. Can you open a terminal window and type `kpsewhich apalike.bst` at a command prompt? (Since you mentioned the use of TeXshop, I'm assuming you're using MacOSX and MacTeX; please advise if this isn't the case.)

Comment: You can use the `biblatex-apa` package,and write ` \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`, but to help you efficiently, you  should post a minimal example of your present code to show you what has to be changed..

Comment: @Bernard have tried that, and it comes up with an error because my bib file isn't created using biblatex?

Comment: @Mico thank you so so much for your help it has worked and you are amazing, you explained the editing of the .bst file so well in your answer to that question! All other explanations of that solution were so confusing for me (the village idiot, apparently). Thank you for your help I so appreciate it!

Comment: @referencingstressesmeout - You're most welcome!